# Image in texture, adjusting the UV, three js

Tags: three.js

I am stuck!
I am trying to map a image on to a surface in three js. It has something to do with UV mapping. I have tried to understand

I create the shape using

```
var i, verts = [];
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    verts.push(createVert(i, Hex.FLAT));
}
hexShape = new THREE.Shape(verts);
```

I have read http://paulyg.f2s.com/uv.htm, [Custom UVgenerator Three.js for extrudedgeometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336027/custom-uvgenerator-three-js-for-extrudedgeometry), [UV mapping in THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317412/uv-mapping-in-three-js), [THREE.js generate UV coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774648/three-js-generate-uv-coordinate).

They use a square, I am using hex/triangles. 
I am loading the image:

```
    if (true) {
    texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("data/mylogo.png",{}, onText, onErr);
} else {
    var textLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    textLoader.load("data/hemp_logoB.png", {}, onText, onErr);
    function onErr(err) {
        console.log('ERR ', err);
    }

    function onText(text) {
        console.log('TEXTLOADED  ', text);
        var t = text;
        var img = t.image;
        console.log(img.height, img.width);
        texture = text;
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        update();
    }
}
```

I the extrude the hex.

```
    geo = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(hexShape, extrudeSettings);
```

I even have made the face and side different

```
var mats = [imgMaterial, sideMaterial];
var mat = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(mats);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
```

I am seeing just a tiny dot in the center of the hex that is the image.  On the shape ( geo) I have 44 faces**

I think I need a uvGenerator or custom uv. The size on the image is 256x256 but I can make it any size***.  The documentation use square surfaces this a is a hex surface.

Ideas???

** Should is be 24? 6 + 6 + 12 top + bottom + (6 * 2) sides
*** mylogo.png was generated from SVG file, I would like to use SVG for image on surface.